# Python logging config file with 'w' argument

Tags: python, logging

I wish to use a configfile to set a "RotatingFileHandler".
I am not able to make the filemode taken in account, it seems always read as 'a'
below the section I use in my configfile:

```
[handler_filehandler]
class=handlers.RotatingFileHandler
level=DEBUG
formatter=simpleFormatter
args=('lf.log','a',100,3,None,0)
```

Everthing around is OK, i can change the logfilename, change maxBytes and backupCount
but if i change 'a' by 'w' file logs still appended
i read the doc, restarted from scratch since many hours, but didn't success ...

Comment: Welcome! Do you want the log to be truncated each time a process begins writing to it?

Comment: I wish the log file to be erased at each start, not appended, so i assume that is the 'w' filemode according to the doc